# Disable the growing ability of an element

Tags: html, css

minimal reproduction of the problem :

```css
.fixed{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(220,220, 220);
}

.wrapper{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0,200, 0, 0.1);
  width: fit-content;
}

p{
  display: inline-block
}

body{
}

.text{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(220,220, 220);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="text">
    this long paragraph should not increase the size of the parent but as you can see, it doessdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you remove the text div, you can see that the green wrapper's width is computed depending on the 3 fixed blocks, an this is exactly what I want.

But I would like to have a text, whose width could not exceed that of the parent.

If you add content to the text div, you can see that it grows and make the green wrapper's size to increase too

Imo there are two workarounds :

- Use a fixed width, but that doesn't suits my needs, i want the size to depend on the fixed blocks.
- Out the text from the flow, using a text-wrapper div with width 100%, position relative, and the text div would have an absolute position. It works, but in this case I need the text-wrapper's heigth to be computed depending on its child, and it's not possible because it is out of the flow

Thanks a lot in advance for reading and helping, tell me if I'm not clear enougth

Comment: as a side note using `width: fit-content;` is like setting `inline-block` but with less support

Comment: @TemaniAfif it doesn't seems to work. I already tried to put that on the text or on a text-wrapper div. I tested on chrome and firefox.

Comment: no, I meant you are using fit-content in your code which you can replace by display:inline-block

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't understand your answer. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use `width:min-content;` combined with `min-width:100%` but you should pay attention to the support of `min-content` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility)

```css
.fixed{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(220,220, 220);
}

.wrapper{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0,200, 0, 0.1);
  display:inline-block;
}

p{
  display: inline-block
}

body{
}

.text{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(220,220, 220);
  width:min-content;
  min-width:calc(100% - 1em);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="text">
    this long paragraph should not increase the size of the parent but as you can see, it doessdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, it works !
It's too bad that the margin cannot be applied in this case, but if you know the margin, calc does the trick

Comment: @dc-p8 or you replace the margin with padding on the top wrapper then it will be easier

Comment: using a text-wrapper div on top of the text, you don't need to use calc()

Answer (score 0):

If I was able to understand you correctly, then you want to fit the width of the lower row with the upper 3 columns width.

You can calculate the width of the 3 columns (5em each) by taking into consideration the margins and padding. I used it as width, you can use it as max-width also

```css
.fixed{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(220,220, 220);
}

.wrapper{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0,200, 0, 0.1);
  width: fit-content;
}

p{
  display: inline-block
}

body{
}

.text{
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(220,220, 220);
  width: 19.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed but unknown</div>
  <div class="text">
    this long paragraph should not increase the size of the parent but as you can see, it doessdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: he said : *Use a fixed width, but that doesn't suits my needs, i want the size to depend on the fixed blocks.*

Comment: Thanks for you help but unfortunatly, this is not a real world environment. Actually, i don't know how many fixed elements exists, and I would be really dirty to use a JS-based solution